# UNABLE TO Load Mongodb library

Tags: mongodb

i am  new  in  mongodb , i'm just trying to include a mongo driver php_mongo_1.5.4-5.5-vc9-nts-x86_64.dll
but  i'm getting warning

`PHP Startup:Unable to load dynamic library
 G:\software\php\ext\php_mongo.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

---

If  i'm  using lower version of driver  then  another problem arousing

```
The program can't start because libsasl.dll is missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I  reinstalled many time but  didn't find any  the solution..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you downloaded the 64 bits version of the driver (x86_64)
In the 1.5.4 zip here, you can try same one without the x86_64
https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you just copy that **libsasl.dll** file and paste into bin folder of apache.
 copy your libsasl.dll and paste it into C:\xampp\apache\bin

and start the apache server your problem will be solved and Mongodb driver will be loaded successfully.

that's it.